# How do I create a column that gives the sum of all rows within 5 minutes previous of a given rows timestamp in DB2 SQL?

Tags: sql, sum, db2

I am trying to sum over rows that have a timestamp within 5 minutes previous to the timestamp of any given row. The issue I have faced is that there is no predefined number of rows that could be within the previous 5 minutes and counting 5 minute intervals from the initial timestamp will not give the desired outcome.

The table below shows the desired output:

| TimeStamp | Sales | SUM_PREVIOUS_5_MINS_SALES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18:04:03 | 2 | 2 |
| 18:05:23 | 5 | 7 |
| 18:05:58 | 3 | 10 |
| 18:09:34 | 4 | 12 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses a window function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(sales) over (order by extract(epoch from timestamp)
                        range between 299 preceding and current row
                       ) as sales_prev_5_minutes
from t;
```

Note:  `299 = 5 * 60 - 1`, i.e. the number of seconds in 5 minutes (well, minus one because the current row is included).

Comment: Db2 doesn't support expressions for group bounds of `RANGE | ROWS`. See the `group-bound1` description of [OLAP specification](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=expressions-olap-specification). So, you should change `(5 * 60) -1` to `299` to make it work in Db2.

Comment: I have no idea. It's such an implementation probably.